# Next/Previous Post Links in single-[custom-post-type].php file

Tags: custom-post-types, next-post-link, previous-post-link

I have a post type 'location' that is a listing for each branch of a multi-branch company. I want to add a Left and Right arrow on each individual location post that will allow the users to cycle through the various locations. I'm trying to use the previous_post_link() and next_post_link() functions to achieve this, but when I use them, nothing is returned.

Here is my code for single-location.php:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="inner-content" class="wrap cf">
            <main id="main" class="m-all t-2of3 d-5of7 cf" role="main" itemscope itemprop="mainContentOfPage" itemtype="http://schema.org/Blog">
                <?php previous_post_link('%link', 'Previous post »'); ?> | <?php next_post_link('%link', 'Next post »'); ?>
                <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( 'cf' ); ?> role="article" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
                        <section class="entry-content cf" itemprop="articleBody">        
                            <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                           <?php the_content(); ?>            
                        </section> <?php // end article section ?>
                    </article>
                <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
            </main>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I've tried every variation on:

```
<?php previous_post_link('%link', 'Previous post »'); ?> | <?php next_post_link('%link', 'Next post »'); ?>
```

that I can find on this site, and many other places I've searched, and no matter which of the 30 location posts I view, all I see in that space is the vertical pipe separator (|). I've tried the code inside, and outside of the loop with the same results.

What am I missing?

Comment: http://bryantwebdesign.com/code/previous-next-navigation-for-custom-post-types/

Comment: Something is breaking your page, a filter, `query_posts`, bad custom query, it could be anything. Turn debug on, deactivate plugins, switch to a bundled theme etc. Update Wordpress

Comment: I've already tried every version of the code on that page, prior to asking this question, and they all return nothing.

Comment: Have you actually tried what I suggested in order to debug this. The behavior you are seeing are not normal and is definitely caused by something **outside** of core, so it has to be something in you theme or in a plugin. You can try a million variations of the code and it will not work. You **have to** debug and establish where the issue is coming from. One other thing I forgot, flush your rewrite rules